# Quiero ordenar una coleccion de objetos de active record pero pasando dos de ellos hasta el final de la colección

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Quiero obtener los registros de un modelo llamado CommonExercies ordenados por code de forma ascendente pero pasando hasta el final dos de ellos, en este caso none y other, no se que otro método utilizar aparte de order, alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

```
irb(main):001:0> CommonExercise.order(code: :asc)   CommonExercise Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "common_exercise".* FROM "common_exercise" ORDER BY "common_exercise"."code" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CommonExercise id: 1, code: "cycling", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">,
#<CommonExercise id: 2, code: "gym", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">, #<CommonExercise id: 3, code: "kickbox", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">, #<CommonExercise id: 7, code: "none", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">,
#<CommonExercise id: 8, code: "other", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">, #<CommonExercise id: 4, code: "run", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">, #<CommonExercise id: 6, code: "swim", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">,
#<CommonExercise id: 5, code: "yoga", created_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31", updated_at: "2019-04-03 17:43:31">]> irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías excluir esos códigos de la primera consulta e incluirlos después:

```
ces = CommonExercise.where.not(code: ['none', 'other']).order(code: :asc)
ces.concat(CommonExercise.where(code: ['none', 'other']).order(code: :asc))
```

aunque "creo" que para lo que requieres ni siquiera es necesaria una tabla.
Podrías agregar una constante agregando los `code` en el modelo que requieras y usando el orden que tu desees:

```
COMMON_EXERCISES = %w[cycling gym kickbox run swim yoga none other].freeze
```

para luego simplemente agregar los `code` como string en tu tabla y agregarle un indexado acorde a la consulta que realices en vez de relacionarlo con una tabla extra.

Comment: Gracias Alter, aunque no existe el método concat para una relación de activerecord, seguiré buscando como hacerle

Comment: @CarlosMorfinDiaz claro que existe, de hecho probé en mi propio `rails console` antes de enviarte la respuesta. Puedes revisar por ti mismo que existe, tanto [en la documentación](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat) como en el [código fuente](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L114) de rails. Saludos